# Setting up keyboard shortcuts to jump to closest input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there simple JavaScript or jQuery script to navigate around form fields, similar to what phpMyAdmin does with dynamic fields. When you click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> it "tabs" to the next field.

This is extending from the default <kbd>Tab</kbd> (go to next) and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (go to previous). I want the navigation to be a bit more extensive by adding up, down, left right, end, home and by rows/columns.

Comment: Why would you want this instead of tab/shift+tab?

Comment: because tab goes to next, shift tab goes to previous. I want to navigate around form fields by up, down, left right, end, beginning by rows/columns.

Comment: You might want to add that to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it would look something like this:

```
$('input').keypress(function(){
    //if correct key combination
        $(this).next('input').focus();
});
```

Ah, from your comment: "because tab goes to next, shift tab goes to previous. I want to navigate around form fields by up, down, left right, end, beginning by rows/columns."

If you want a 2d grid of inputs you might need to use the ids:

```
<input id="input_1_1" />
```

(id = input_x_y)

The javascript would then be something like:

```
$('input').keypress(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id.split("_");
    // if up:
        $('#input_'+id[0]+'_'+(id[1] - 1)).focus();
    // if down:
        $('#input_'+id[0]+'_'+(id[1] + 1)).focus();
    // if left:
        $('#input_'+(id[0] - 1)+'_'+id[1]).focus();
    // if right:
        $('#input_'+(id[0] + 1)+'_'+id[1]).focus();
});
```

Comment: Obviously you would need to know the order when you are laying out the html